# Service sent back a fault indicating it is too busy to process the request. Please retry later. Please see the inner exception for fault details

Tags: wcf

I am using one WCF service that deployed in server designed in .net 4.0v . But after processing all queues it is generating exception i.e. service sent back a fault indicating it is too busy to process the request. Please retry later. Please see the inner exception for fault details. I am using "wsHttpBinding"

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomSecurity">
          <security>
            <localServiceSettings maxPendingSessions="1000" />
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

 <binding name="CustomSecurityxxx" closeTimeout="01:00:00"
          openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:00:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Thanks in advance. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is fixed.

I increased the serviceThrottling values

`<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/>` from 200 and simply enclosed the service instances in using block so that the block will handle the scope of the object like initializing and disposing

Sample code syntax is as follows

```
xxxClient ServiceObject;

    using (ServiceObject= new xxxClient()) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            your code goes here
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ServiceObject.Abort();
                        }  

                    }
```

Hope it will help to those facing the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. did you increate serviceThrottling on client config or server config?